# How can I update a file through editing a QTableView?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I am trying to create a program that utilizes a `QTableView` built on a `QStandardItemModel`, but I want the model to get its data from a .txt file that holds all the information.  I know how to get the data from the file into the model, but I am unsure of how to update the file whenever the user edits the table view by double clicking and changing the text.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: The date of your .txt file has any format?

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: If you want to display the data as a table, then at least one should be able to recognize the rows and columns in the file.

Comment: For example in the format CSV organizes the data by commas and endlines.

Comment: I'll have to do some more research on that, I was planning on making a random access file to hold the data.  Do you have any recommendations for the second half of my question?

Comment: Using a database may be a better approach to safe your data in realtime. Changing a CSV file often results in rewriting the complete file, because you are not able to insert some characters in a file without rewriting everything from that point on.